# Chrome DNS unflushable?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dns

I have a really weird problem and I can't figure out whats going on.

When I visit fc.boilerroom.tv on my Chrome install I receive a domain parked page. If I visit it with either Firefox or Safari, it resolves to the correct address 94.76.204.165 and the site shows up.

My first idea was to flush the DNS cache by visiting  chrome://net-internals/#dns and clicking the flush host cache button. No dice. I then cleared all caches. No help.

I then tried to install the DNS Flusher extension for Chrome; also no resolution.

I then tried Wireshark, but that just showed me what I already experienced: my Chrome install resolves fc.boilerroom.tv to a different IP than Firefox and Safari.

I've tried using Chrome on other computers but they resolve fc.boilerroom.tv to the correct IP so it must be a local issue.

Anybody have any idea what's going on here?

--
UPDATED: 
I am an idiot. Please see Bon's answer to see how big.

Comment: I am on MacOS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just you.  I've never been to this domain either... ever.  But, using Chrome with Windows XP, when I go to [fc.boilerroom.tv](http://fc.boilerroom.tv) this is what I get...

[image]

when I go to `94.76.204.165` I get this...

[image]

and when I ping fc.boilerroom.tv it resolves to 94.76.204.165

[image]

I have repeated these results with Internet Explorer and Firefox, as well as on two different computers.  So, the fact that your Firefox and Safari produce the same page for both these addresses seems to be an issue as well.  Are these the results you are getting in Chrome?

Comment: This is actually the desired result: It is supposed to resolve to 94.76.204.165. It is a server with multiple vhosts so if you visit the domain directly, you'll get that page, if you visit fc.boilerroom.tv you should see the site. Which you do, so it works. When I visit fc.boilerroom.tv on Chrome, I get to see this: http://i.imgur.com/PVIoa.png. When I visit that domain on Firefox or Safari, I see the correct site.

Comment: look carefully at the domain up there in your browser.  you keep on saying "fc.boilerroom.tv" but in that image you just showed me, it is "fc.boileroom.tv"  only one **R**

Comment: THANK YOU BON, that was actually it... I kept relying on Chrome's autofill feature and I missed that typo every time. Unbelievably stupid. Thanks again for your patience and keen eye!

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted chrome after flushing the DNS and clearing all browsing data?

Do you have this option enabled?

Predict network actions to improve page load performance

If so, disable it and restart.

Have you tried flushing Dns from the terminal?

1) Change to “root” by using the following command:
su -
Enter the root password when prompted. If you don’t know the “root” password for your system, you can set it by following this Apple KB article: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528

2) Type in the following command to flush the DNS:
dscacheutil -flushcache

Comment: I've disabled Predict network actions to improve page load performance and restarted the browser. No solution. I've also tried dscacheutil -flushcache to no avail. I don't think the problem is on the system level, as Firefox and Safari correctly showed the site before, even without dscacheutil. The problem just occurs with Chrome :S

Comment: do you have any proxy configured?

Comment: Nope, no proxies. This happens from two different locations as well, so it's not likely to be the internet connection either.

Comment: Is the proxy option disabled in chrome also? Have you tried opening that page in incognito mode? (Wrench icon, New Incognito Window)

Comment: It says "Google Chrome is using your computer's system proxy settings to connect to the network." In System Preferences no proxies are set up. Incognito mode shows the same page (the wrong one).

Comment: What do you get when pinging fc.boilerroom.tv? Have you tried reinstalling google chrome? Are you singed in on chrome? I know if you are signed in it gets all your history, data, etc from the web. So if you are logged in try login out.

Comment: Bon just provided the answer to an incredibly stupid error on my part. Thank you Federico for your answers and your time.